# Test automation with geb and groovy

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, spock, geb

I am not sure if I do not understand something, but I have problem with write automation tests using Intellij IDEA, groovy, spock, geb and gradle. I have some experience with java, testng, pure webdriver and maven. But now I'm confused a little.

Does Intellij IDEA have some problem with integration groovy and geb? I feel like I write in notepad. Intellij doesn't prompt me nothing about elements from page, methods, when I write tests scripts. I must remember about everything. It's shouldn't look like this.

My structure looks like:
-pages (exteded from Page)
-tests where I use my pages, static content from pages etc.

Where is my mistake, or that is how work geb and groovy?

Comment: IntelliJ's Spock support is great, I use it every day. Which problem exactly do you have? What have you tried to insrtall or configure that does not work?

Comment: @kriegaex The topic is associated with difference between strong and dynamic typing. Documentation of Geb is clear and that was the answer for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain things you need to do to get authoring assistance when working with Geb in IntelliJ - have a look at [*IDE support* chapter of *The Book of Geb*](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#ide-support).